# Icon not showing in Menu using AVD

Tags: android, android-menu

I have problem on this menu.I already set the icon for it,but it's not showing when I run my  AVD,but if i will install this to my device it will work properly. can you help me on this please I am still learning android, why is it that it will not work on my AVD. Thank you in advance.

Here is my code

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
        <item android:id="@+id/add" 
              android:title="Add"   
              android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"></item>
        <item android:id="@+id/edit" 
              android:title="Edit" 
              android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"></item>
         <item android:id="@+id/delete" 
               android:title="Delete" 
               android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"></item>
     </menu>
```

This is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.mymenu"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

   <uses-sdk
       android:minSdkVersion="8"
       android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
             android:name="com.example.mymenu.MainActivity"
             android:label="@string/app_name" >
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
               </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>

     </manifest>
```

Comment: can you put your code, and the AVD details??

Comment: If you mean the launch icon, post your manifest file (especially the entry point `activity` there).

Answer (score 0):

Your new Icon should be place in every drawable folders, then it will compatible with all

Comment: Hi,I am just using the default icon in android,ic_launcher.png